# Проблема с функцией в python

Tags: python

У меня есть функция:

```
def Tests(way):
    global event
    keyboard, question, answer, myline = createBoardForTests(way)
    send_msg(event.user_id, question, keyboard=keyboard)
    while a:
        for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                if event.from_user and event.to_me:
                    if event.text.lower() == 'вернуться к списку предметов':
                        keyboard = create_keyboard(event.text.lower())
                        send_msg(event.user_id, message='Выберите один из предметов, сложность зависит от количества правильно решенных вами задач.', keyboard=keyboard)
                        break
                    elif event.text.lower() == answer.lower():
                        send_msg(event.user_id, 'Правильно! Следующий вопрос. ', keyboard=keyboard)
                        Tests(way)
                    elif event.text.lower() == myline[0] or event.text.lower() == myline[1] or event.text.lower() == myline[2] or event.text.lower() == myline[3]:
                        send_msg(event.user_id, 'Неверный ответ! Следующий вопрос. ', keyboard=keyboard)
                        Tests(way)
        print('Вышел из цикла for')
        break
    print('Вышел из цикла while')
```

Она проверяет правильность ответа пользователя боту через vk_api.

В строках:

```
if event.text.lower() == 'вернуться к списку предметов':
    keyboard = create_keyboard(event.text.lower())
    send_msg(event.user_id,
         message='Выберите один из предметов, сложность зависит от количества правильно решенных вами задач.',
         keyboard=keyboard)
    break
```

видно, что если сообщение пользователя будет равно 'вернуться к списку предметов', то выполнится функция send_msg и цикл for закроется. После закрытия цикла for выведится 'Вышел из цикла for', далее закрывается цикл while, и выведится 'Вышел из цикла while'. И здесь, по идее функция Tests должна завершиться.

Место кода, где вызывается функция Tests:

```
if response == 'математика':
    Tests('tests\Math.txt')
    print('a')
```

Здесь видно, что после функции Tests должно вывестить 'a', но ничего не выводит
**Но если пользователь еще раз напишет *'вернуться к списку предметов'*, то ЕЩЕ один раз выведутся строки: 'Вышел из цикла for' и 'Вышел из цикла while', + в этот раз функция ПО-НАСТОЯЩЕМУ закроется, и выведится 'a'**

Надеюсь суть работы кода донёс, вот сам вопрос - Как сделать так, чтобы пользователю нужно было написать только 1 раз *вернуться к списку предметов*?

Comment: у вас там еще 2 `if` без `else` - я б так не делал - вы половину случаев теряете, "сожмите" условия - чтобы не было вложенности идобавьте `else`

Comment: @EugeneDennis Если вы про эти строки:
`if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                if event.from_user and event.to_me:`
То там else не нужны

Comment: Т. е. если в первый раз "вернуться", то ничего не выводит, а вот уже после второго "возврата" выводятся сообщения, функция выполняется, и печатается "а"?

Comment: @Jazzis в первый раз выводятся сообщения про завершения циклов, во второй раз еще раз выводятся сообщения про завершения циклов, функция выполняется и печатается 'a'

Comment: @LikeKey Ну значит вы рекурсивно вызвали функцию. Первый выход сработал из рекурсивного вызова, второй - из основного. А зачем у Вас там while?
И зачем вы используете глобальную переменную в качестве переменной цикла?